# How to encode CSP-policy delimiter characters (e.g. semicolon) within parts of source expressions (e.g. URL) in CSP header?

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy

I'm currently writing my CSP policy in NGINX and I need to provide a report-uri that has the *special* character `;` in it. Notice that `;` is valid for an URI path.

```
default-src: 'self'; report-uri: /;index
```

However, the `;` doesn't get recognized as a valid character and so I'm getting following error in my browsers (Chrome) console:

```
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'index'.
```

Is there any way to escape the character or wrap the URI inside a string (inside the header string)? I already tried `\;` and single quote wrapping (I'm using double quotes to wrap the header content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to percent-encode the semicolon as `%3B`. The CSP spec has [the following note](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#source-list-parsing):

> Note: Characters like U+003B SEMICOLON (`;`) and U+002C COMMA (`,`) cannot appear in source expressions directly: if you’d like to include these characters in a source expression, they must be percent encoded as `%3B` and `%2C` respectively.

So the CSP policy shown in the question should instead be written like this:

```
default-src: 'self'; report-uri: /%3Bindex
```